# What is the topological interpretation of continuity of distributions?

Tags: general-topology, continuity, distribution-theory

I was given this definition of continuity in the distributional sense.

> A distribution $T$ over the space of *test* functions $\mathcal{D}$ is continuous if for every sequence of *test* functions $\{ \varphi_j\}_j$ that converges to an element $\varphi$ , the sequence $\{\langle T ,\varphi_j\rangle\}_j $ converges to $\langle T ,\varphi\rangle$.
>
> Where the convergence in the space of *test* functions is defined to be uniform (that includes the  derivatives) and the supports of the functions must subsets of a compact set.

Now, I would like to know if is this equivalent to continuity in the topological sense. That is, that the preimage of every open set is open.

I think that the first think to do would be to define a topology , I'm not sure if the weak  is the right thing to do,  but  Wikipedia's article is way over my head.

**Could someone  explain if they are both equivalent?** If possible, more intuitively than rigorously.

Comment: The topology you are looking for is called the "inductive limit topology". A (relatively) concise definition/construction of this topology, together with a derivation of the most important properties (including the equivalence of continuity of a linear map with the sequential condition you describe) is given in the book "Functional Analysis" by Walter Rudin in Definition 6.3 to Theorem 6.8.

Comment: An addition to the above comments: The topology is not really the "inductive limit topology". Rather, it is the "inductive limit topology for locally convex vector spaces".